# Custom WebViewPage with additional type-parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, inheritance, razor

MVC4 by default uses `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` as base-class for all pages exposing properties like the helpers `Html` and `Ajax` to be used at any point in a Razor-view.

All of my `Model`s inherit from of generic type, e.g.

```
MyModel : BaseModel<SomeComplexType>
```

Is there any chance to get something to work like

```
MyViewPage<TCustom> : WebViewPage<TCustom> where TCustom: BaseModel<???>
```

to expose a property

```
??? MyGenericProperty { get { return Model.CustomProperty;} }
```

which then can be accessed like `@MyGenericProperty.CustomValue` in any `View` the same as `@Html`?

Adding a second parameter to `MyViewPage<TModel, TCustom> : WebViewPage<TModel>` does not seem to work as of each `View` now doesn't even know `@Html` or `@Model`.

Maybe via Reflection, Injection or some other Magic?

**Edit 1**

FrameworkWebViewPage.cshtml

```
public class FrameworkWebViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

and it's generic friend (the one with the two parameters)

```
public class FrameworkWebViewPage<TModel, TViewModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : BaseResponse<TViewModel> where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    protected TViewModel ViewModel { get { return Model.ViewModel; } }

    public override void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot Index.cshtml]

ReSharper complains the following in my Index.cshtml

- `Incorrect number of type parameters. Candidates are: GenericViewModel.Framework.Pages.FrameworkWebViewPage GenericViewModel.Framework.Pages.FrameworkWebViewPage<TModel,TViewModel>` at Line 1
- `Cannot resolve symbol 'Layout'` at Line 4 and
- `Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewModel'` at Line 9

On the other hand it builds without any errors.
At runtime it throws

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0308: The non-generic type 'GenericViewModel.Framework.Pages.FrameworkWebViewPage' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Just in case, this is the implementation of the views model:

```
public class HomeIndexGetResponse : BaseResponse<HomeIndexGetViewModel>
{
}
```

**End Edit 1**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason that wouldn't work as long as your web view inherits from `WebViewPage`.

> Adding a second parameter to MyViewPage : WebViewPage does not seem to work as of each View now doesn't even know @Html or @Model.

Does @MyGeneicProperty work in this case? Do you see any compilation errors? You could try setting `<MvcBuildViews>` in the .csproj file to true and see if you get compilation errors.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx/

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago, but was this question ever answered? I'm also interested in using 2 type arguments for a custom WebViewPage.